# Ideas for a cookie crawler?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, curl, web-crawler

I'm a looking for a PHP/javascript/etc. crawler (bot) who would check given sets of websites and (that's the important part) check which cookies that website sets into user's browser!

I don't even know if it's possible to do something like this, because I know crawlers can check the content of websites and even crawlers can have stored cookies when the user comes to a website, but can he actually read cookies from a website?

So my question is: Isn't this impossible by definition? Can something like this be done? Basically check which cookies a website sets into user browser and for example store them in a variable.

Comment: you basically want to hack a user/website and get their cookies, with javascript you will get only your own cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$sites = array(
"www.google.com",
"www.w3schools.com",
"www.sapo.pt");

foreach ($sites as $site)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://$site");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/$site");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/$site");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
} 
?>
```

This will create cookies of each website crawled in the /tmp/ folder

```
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache       430 Jan 26 20:21 www.google.com
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache       291 Jan 26 20:22 www.sapo.pt
-rw-r--r--  1 apache apache       225 Jan 26 20:21 www.w3schools.com
```

Comment: Okay, thank you, this works well. Only think is this doesn't not eat cookies which are set by javascript right? Is there any way to make this javascript-aware?

Comment: No it doesn't, curl doesn't support javascript :(

Answer (score 0):

Web sites don't (generally) care if a user-agent is a user controlled browser or a bot. Both can read the HTTP response headers that request the user-agent stores a cookie.

The complications come from when a site sets cookies conditionally (as you have to trigger the condition) or with JavaScript (when you'll need to make the bot JavaScript aware).